# How do you simply color one single row using Pandas or to_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

Searched around Google/Stackoverflow for this but there doesn't seem to be a straightforward answer. I simply want to color the first row of my csv file (no condition having to be met first). Basically the row that contains all the column headers/titles, in the color orange.

In my code I have multiple pandas df's that I merged together, then aligned them horizontally to where all the titles are on top, and it looks like a traditional csv file with blank columns in between (df0).

Here is my code:

```
# Simply want to color the first row of this entire panda dataframe, either here or w/to_csv
df_merged = pd.concat([df1, df0, df2, df0, df3, df0, df4], axis=1)


out_path = "C:\\Users\\JohnReese\\Desktop\\G_Trends\\File1.csv"

df_merged.to_csv(out_path, index=False)

f1 = pd.read_csv(out_path, header=None)
```

Is it possible to do this? Like through a function or simplier?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSV, as a format, contains no formatting whatsoever. Neither color nor font nor bold/italic/underline. This isn't a limitation of Pandas or Python, it's a format thing.